# MySQLdb connection error with localhost with different port (eg. 8080)

Tags: python, mysql, localhost, mysql-python

I am trying to connect MySQLdb to MySQL. It was working fine when when my server was localhost and port 80. But due to some reason I had to change the port to 8080. Now how do I specify the port in the connect command?
This is what I was using earlier:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "pymysql")
```

Now my server is "localhost:8080". So where should I give the information regarding this port?
I tried this :

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1:8080", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "pymysql")
```

This is what I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1:8080", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "pymysql")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:8080' (11004)")
```

Please Help !!!

Comment: did you try `"localhost:8080"`? not that it should really matter i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html).

```
connect(parameters...)


    host
        name of host to connect to. Default: use the local host via a UNIX socket (where applicable)
    user
        user to authenticate as. Default: current effective user.
    passwd
        password to authenticate with. Default: no password.
    db
        database to use. Default: no default database.
    port
        TCP port of MySQL server. Default: standard port (3306).
```

Comment: The connection was working without mentioning about the MySQL port 3306. So I was trying just the server host.

Comment: Anyways after giving the port as 3306 it worked fine with host="localhost"

Comment: It works because the default setting for `port` is the default port for mysql (3306).

Answer (score 1):

The ports 8080 or 80 are usually used for web servers not for MySQL

The default port for MySQL is 3306